# Approximate diagonalization (eigendecomposition) of a non-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Suppose that $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is a non-symmetric and diagonalizable matrix with $A=PVP^{-1}$, where $P,V\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $V$ is a diagonal matrix. Here I have only an estimate $\hat A$ of $A$ which was obtained by statistics. Is there any way to approximately decompose $\hat A$ as $\hat A\approx \hat P\hat V{\hat P}^{-1}$ with real-valued $\hat P$ and real-valued diagonal $\hat V$? ($\hat A$ may not be diagonalizable).

Comment: Do you need an eigendecomposition or would an SVD work as well?

Comment: Eigendecomposition. Here $V$ involves the spectral components of a system and it can be proved that $A$ must be diagonalizable.

Comment: A real non-symmetric matrix does not necessarily have real eigenvalues and eigenvectors. They can come in complex conjugate pairs.

Comment: @VictorLiu I know that it is not necessarily diagonalizable and my question is how to perform the "approximate" diagonalization in the real field. The paper in [link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.160.8837&rep=rep1&type=pdf) discussed the similar problem in the complex field.